# How to run slideDown animations separately with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a jQuery animation that can be seen by clicking the **Preview** button on top:

```
$(function(){
    $.each([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], function() {
        var elem = $('<div>').html('Number : ' + this).appendTo($('body')).hide();
        $("body").queue(function(next) {
            elem.slideDown('slow', next);
        });
    });
});
```

http://jsbin.com/anayi3/edit

I have used the `slideDown` animation method. The problem is that all items slide down together. I want each number to display after short delay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An example using recursive anonymous function. Put this inside your document-ready function.

```
  // Array of elements to be animated.
  var elements = $('.your-selector-here li').get();

  (function () {
    // Take out the first element of array, animate it
    // and pass this anonymous function as callback.
    $(elements.shift()).slideDown('slow', arguments.callee);
  })();
​
```

Comment: This is totally smart and elegant. Welcome to SO, Yaggo!

Comment: @Yaggo: great: never thought it can be done that way. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You'l need to use the callback function to animate the next number after the first has finished.  See the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/).

Something like:

```
$('firstNumber').slideDown('slow',function(){ 
    $('secondNumber').slideDown('slow');
});
```

You'll need to call this recursively for each of the numbers.

Comment: Could you please modify the script so that it shows items after some delay. You can edit it there http://jsbin.com/anayi3/edit. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var index = 0;

function animate() {
  elem = $("div:eq(" + index + ")");
  elem.slideDown('slow');
  index++;
  if (index < 10) {
    setTimeout(animate, 500);
  }
}

$(function(){

  for(var i = 1; i < 10 ;i++){
    var elem = $('<div>').html('Number : ' + i).appendTo($('body')).hide();
  }
  animate();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to attach all animations to some element's [queue](http://api.jquery.com/queue/) in order to run them sequentially

```
$(function(){
    $.each([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], function() {
        var elem = $('<div>').html('Number : ' + this).appendTo($('body')).hide();
        $("body").queue(function(next) {
            elem.slideDown('slow', next)
        });
    });
});
```

Here all animations are attached to "body", but that can be any element. The "next" syntax is new in jquery 1.4.